# Defining a long string in Razor

Tags: syntax, razor

I want to define a long string and use it as a parameter in a helper class.

I have the following code which does not compile

```
@{
var code ="
new TEL_Helper 
{ 
   URI = "abc@domain.com", 
   Type = TEL_TelecomType.Email, 
   Use = TEL_TelecomUse.VacationHome 
}"

Html.SyntaxXML(code)
}
```

How do I define the string that spans multiple lines and has line breaks.

and the solution I used was :

```
@{
var code =@"
new TEL_Helper 
{ 
    URI = 'abc@domain.com', 
    Type = TEL_TelecomType.Email, 
    Use = TEL_TelecomUse.VacationHome 
}";

 Html.SyntaxXML(code);
 }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the standard C# verbatim string literal.

```
            var code = @"
new TEL_Helper 
{ 
   URI = ""abc@domain.com"", 
   Type = TEL_TelecomType.Email, 
   Use = TEL_TelecomUse.VacationHome 
}"
```

Comment: I tried that, it still tries to match the "}" in the string definition with the opening "{" in the code block.

Comment: @BENBUNCoder: Then you're making a mistake somewhere; Razor does support this.  Check your nested quotes.

Comment: @BENBUNCoder WHen you use the @ verbatim syntax, nested quotes in your string have to be escaped by using a second ", so in SLaks example you need to do ""abc@domain.com"" like he shows.

Answer (score 0):

Just break the string out into pieces and concatenate:

```
@{
    var code =
         "new TEL_Helper " +
         "{ " +
             "URI = \"abc@domain.com\"," +
         "}";
}
```

Don't forget to escape your quotes within the string.

Comment: yuk.  I guess it answers the question but it's so cumbersome.  makes copy/paste from other sources impossible (but no -1)